# Python code not working in watson-studio?

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-studio, watson-studio-desktop

I wrote a line of code in watson studio 
As 
   Rdd = sc.parallelized (range(100))
Output
    SC is not defined 
How to solve this please help some buddy

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you done any debugging yourself? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Watson Studio has multiple types of environments.
There is likelihood that instead of using PySpark based runtime environment , you must have selected Python based runtime environment.
Please make sure to check your runtime environment.
[image]

For more details on runtimes:-
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/spark-envs.html

Answer (score 0):

`SC is not defined` looks like the result of a Python Traceback (error message). It means that `sc` references something that has not been created yet.

I suggest checking your spelling to see if maybe you declared `sc` under a different name. Also, Python is case-sensitive, so beware of that.

Comment: The spelling is correct. `sc` is the pre-defined Spark context, if code is being executed in a runtime with Spark. In runtimes without Spark, it is undefined.